# Vertically align label with checkbox

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my label vertically aligned with my checkbox? The text appears higher vertically.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" style="float: left; margin-top:0.5em;" />
<label style="font-size:12px; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em;">Remember me</label>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `margin-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#remember {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1px; /* updated this */
}
#remember + label {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" />
<label>Remember me</label>
```

Side note: Avoid using inline css

Answer (score 0):

change `display:block` to `display: inline-block`

And give a `margin-top` of around `5px`

Comment: @webkit true, but I still had to change it to `inline-block` to get it to work in JSFiddle